# Find ancestor tr based on hidden input value in a td using Python and Selenium WebDriver 2

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get WebDriver to hover over a table row in order to make a "delete" link appear. Each row contains a hidden input with an item name as the value, and since the item name will be known by people writing tests (but the specific row in which it appears will not) I am trying to locate the row using the item name.

My basic plan is to locate the input and then look for its ancestor .

I've tried with both Xpath and CSS, and while I can get close (I can get the input) I can't seem to get back up to the  element. Since the input is hidden I can't simply hover over it.

Here's what I've got:

```
def delete_row_by_item_or_task_name(self, item_name=None, task_name=None):
    try:
        if item_name:
            name = item_name
            table_id = 'invoice-items'
        if task_name:
            name = task_name
            table_id = 'invoice-time'
        # tr = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#" + table_id + " input[value=" + name + "]")

        tr = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='" + table_id + "']/tbody/tr/td/div/div/input[contains(.,'" + name + "')]")
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        self.hover(tr)
        self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Delete line').click()
```

The CSS selector works, if I drop a pdb in and check the variable 'td' is a web element. But as I mentioned I can't hover over a hidden input and trying to add /ancestor::tr results in an exception (WebDriverException).

The Xpath results in a NoSuchElement exception with or without the /ancestor::tr

Please let me know if any information needed is missing, I would be happy to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your xpath, I am assuming your HTML looks something like:

```
<table id="table_id">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <input value="item_name" type="hidden" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want the `<tr>` that contains the input with value "item_name", then you can use the following xpath:

```
"//table[@id='" + table_id + "']/tbody/tr[./td/div/div/input[contains(@value, '" + name + "')]]"
```

This will return the `<tr>` element directly, so you do not need to find the ancestor of the input element. Basically this is saying, 'find me the tr that contains the input element'.